# Firebase connection state listener returns false in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

Everytime I run this script, it shows "not connected" first time and after that "connected". Why does it always trigger "not connected" first? 
There are some topics with same issue like this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103727/firebase-connection-state-always-returning-false-on-first-run), but no answers.

```
var connectedRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/connected");
connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() === true) {
    alert("connected");
  } else {
    alert("not connected");
  }
});
```

Comment: Please make sure that `snap.val()` contains the true value as string or bool, and then compare accordingly , you can check that by printing the `snap.val()` before `if`

Comment: Used also JSON.stringify(snap), I see always first time false, and then true.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal, on purpose functionality of Firebase to avoid any race conditions.

Refer the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities

> **Note that your app should queue the disconnect operations before a
>   user is marked online**, to avoid any race conditions in the event that
>   the client's network connection is lost before both commands can be
>   sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

When your page load, the Firebase client is initially not connected to its backend servers. So it marks `.info/connected` as `false`.

It then starts building the connection, which may take some time. If/when it established the connection it marks `.info/connected` as `true`.

This is the expected behavior. If it is causing problems for your app, it's likely that you're trying to use the indicator for something it may not be directly suitable for. If that is the case, it's probably easier to help if you share your use-case.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. But basically, I need to show alert , if no firebase connection. Everytime user open page, need to detect if firebase is down or if connection goes down anytime.

Comment: As expected, this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Using `.info/connected` to show a modal alert is a bad user experience. Using it to show a "connected to server" indicator is typically a better user experience.